# Junit Test of Getters. How can I write it

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5

I have a class:

```
public final class Core {
    private final Deque<Double> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    private final HashMap<String, Double> values = new HashMap<>();

    public Deque<Double> getStack() {
        return stack;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Double> getValues() {
        return values;
    }
}
```

I need a Junit test for this getters, but I don't know how to write it correctly

Comment: What would you be testing? That those getters indeed return something?

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt, and explain what problem(s) you are having with it.

Comment: it's pretty pointless to test setters or getters, since they don't really impact the data, they just 'pass' it.

Comment: Sorry guys. But I was told just make sure the getters work. The unit test should do this. =(

Comment: @Stultuske i totally agree! but I received such a task - I need to do it for practice.

Comment: ok. run a get and check that it returns a new, empty map/..

Comment: @venus is this homework or a real world setting? Because in the first case you could assert that `getStack` returns a `Dequeue`, for example. If it is for work, ask whoever told you to test this class what they want tested here.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I am now being taught to write tests more deeply for new project. i am so so so junior dev. they said that even such code can be tested. I don't know how to write correctly, because I haven't tested such empty classes. I apologize if this seems like a trifle.

Comment: I would not be writing or testing getters and setters. Use Lombok to generate them. It can also annotate them so they won't be counted in code coverage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get each property and add something to their collection

Then get each property again and verify that what you added is still there

Comment: with assertEquals?

Comment: @venus no, do an assertContains or equivalent

Comment: could you write an example?

Comment: @venus no, you're going to have to put more effort than that in to this

Comment: venus, how is the description Novaterata gave you not clear?

Comment: this is a weird example because there is no constructor or setter to be able to inject a specific Map or Deque, so the only way you can interact with the object is by modifying the collections and checking that what you modified is the same thing returned by each getter

Comment: @Stultuske it's clear, but I don't know how to access the field class in the test.

Comment: @venus the only way is via the getter

Comment: var myStack = aCore.getStack()

Comment: @Novaterata  I tried to write like this, but it doesn't work. is this the wrong approach? ` @Test
    public void testGetter_getStack() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        final Core core = new Core();
        final Field field = core.getClass().getDeclaredField("stack");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(core, 70.0);

        final Deque<Double> result = core.getStack();

        Assertions.assertEquals(result, 70.0);

    }`

Comment: no. why are you using reflection? just execute a getter on the instance.

Comment: The whole point of this is probably to demonstrate encapsulation. You have a class Core that contains _private_ member fields that are only accessible via _public_ getter methods.

Comment: @Novaterata yes, that's the thing

Comment: @Novaterata This assignment has me stumped. I feel stupid when I did something harder, but I can’t do this task

Comment: @venus you do understand how getters work? how familiar are you with the OO basics?

Comment: A getter is just a method (a function of an obect) that returns the value of a field. There is effectively no different from using aCore.stack and aCore.getStack(). You aren't allowed to use aCore.stack because stack is private, so you just use aCore.getStack()

Comment: Do you know about interfaces? Every class has an implicit interface that is just the methods of the object, but they can also explicitly implement a defined interface like AutoCloseable. Fields are _not_ part of the interface, but getters are.

Comment: ok guys i figure out! thx to all =D